# Moving shardlet with Elastic Scale and forcing order of Reference tables copied

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

I would like to move a shardlet from one shard to another. I'm using the Azure Elastic Scale libraries and the provided Split/Merge/Move example.

When trying to move a shardlet I keep receiving an error because the tool is copying a (reference) table to a different shard, but in the wrong order. The tool is trying to copy the `Firmware` table, which has a FK relation to the `User` table. However, this `User` table isn't copied yet, so when it tries to execute an `INSERT` command, it fails because the FK-relation isn't met.

The documentation on the site states the following:

> Referential Integrity: The Split/Merge service analyzes dependencies
>   between tables and uses foreign key-primary key relationships to stage
>   the operations for moving reference tables and shardlets. In general,
>   reference tables are copied first in dependency order, then shardlets
>   are copied in order of their dependencies within each batch. This is
>   necessary so that FK-PK constraints on the target shard are honored as
>   the new data arrives.

Is there a way I can manage the order when a table will be processed?

Maybe by changing the order they are registered?

Answer (score 1):

Can you double-check whether both tables (Firmware and User) are registered as reference tables in the SchemaInfoCollection in your shard map? Spelling, uppercase vs. lowercase...

Split/Merge uses the information in the SchemaInfoCollection to get the list of reference tables and to then analyze their dependencies. So, this scenario should be taken care of unless we have a bug.

If you have the correct information in the shard map, this would be a bug we would want to look at. Let me know if this turns out to be the case. You can reach me at torsteng(at)microsoftDOTcom.

Thanks,
Torsten